# External Java Script React Redux (Tawk.to) Unmount

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, widget, tawk.to

I am trying at add Tawk.To Widget to my React APP.

I have added the widget (java script) to my App and it loads perfectly when I open the page but when I move to another page the Script is still there.

Can any one guide me how to Unmount this script when I move to another page?

The following is the code I have used.

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Footer from "../Footer";



class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.id    = 'tawkId';
    script.async = true;
    script.src   = 'https://embed.tawk.to/' + '5f01080d223d045fcb7b5265' + '/default';
    script.charset = 'UTF-8';
    script.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <Footer active_chat={true} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the script of id "tawkId" onComponentUnmount()

```
componentWillUnmount() {
     document.getElementById("tawkId").remove();
}
```

Comment: Hello,
I updated the code as follows but still its not hiding when moving to next page.
```class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.id    = 'tawkId';
    script.async = true;
    script.src   = 'https://embed.tawk.to/' + '5f01080d223d045fcb7b5265' + '/default';
    script.charset = 'UTF-8';
    script.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
     document.getElementById("tawkId").remove();
}```